# Screens not changing after CommonActions.reset even though onStateChange fires with right state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens in a route:

{ A, B }

When going back from B to A, we can't unmount B or we'll lose it's info. So I'm calling:

```
export function swapRoutes() {
    navigationRef.current?.dispatch(state => {
        const routes = state.routes.reverse();
        return CommonActions.reset({
            ...state,
            routes,
            index: routes.length - 1
        });
    });
}
```

This works when going from B back to A. I get { B, A } and the screen shows up.

However, when I do the same thing when I try then to go from A to B again, and call the same method, the `onStateChanged` fires and shows the right state { A, B } and index 1, but the screen doesn't change, it just has A at the top.

Any idea what could cause the screens not to reflect the state?

Also: these are complex screens so I can't just push another screen A or B during these transitions, one of them is a webview and one of them is a module. All I'm trying to do is swap them without re-rendering. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because `.reverse()` mutates the array, so the array reference doesn't change and React Navigation doesn't think that the array has changed.

You need to make sure not to mutate it (e.g. by spreading it to a new array first):

```js
    navigationRef.current?.dispatch(state => {
        const routes = [...state.routes].reverse();
        return CommonActions.reset({
            ...state,
            routes,
            index: routes.length - 1
        });
    });
```

Comment: It worked! I genuinely cannot thank you enough! All the best and take care.